# boost::bind для перегруженного метода

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/bind/bind.hpp"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"

class a
{
 public:
  a() {}
  virtual ~a() {}
  void foo(std::string &a) {} // <-- Вероятная причина
  void foo(const char *addr_) {} // <-- Вероятная причина
  virtual void foo1() {}
};

class b : public a
{
 public:
  b() {}
 ~b() {}
  void foo1() {}
};


int main ()
{
    b bb;
    std::string s("123");
    boost::async(boost::bind(&b::foo, bb, s)); // <-- ошибка

    return 0;
}
```

Данный код выдает вот такую ошибку, когда программа пытается забиндить функцию b::foo

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   2   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   3   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   4   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf7<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   5   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf7<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   6   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf6<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   7   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf6<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   8   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf5<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   9   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf5<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   10  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf4<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   11  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf4<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   12  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf3<R,T,B1,B2,B3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3) const,A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   13  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf3<R,T,B1,B2,B3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3),A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   14  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf2<R,T,B1,B2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2) const,A1,A2,A3)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   15  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf2<R,T,B1,B2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2),A1,A2,A3)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   16  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf1<R,T,B1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1) const,A1,A2)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   17  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf1<R,T,B1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1),A1,A2)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   18  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void) const,A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   19  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void) const,A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   20  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void) const,A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   21  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void),A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type' D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   22  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void),A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type' D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   23  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(void),A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type' D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   24  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   25  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   26  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   27  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf8<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   28  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf7<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   29  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf7<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   30  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf7<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   31  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf7<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   32  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf6<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   33  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf6<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   34  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf6<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   35  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf6<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   36  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf5<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   37  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf5<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   38  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf5<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   39  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf5<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   40  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf4<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   41  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf4<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   42  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf4<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   43  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf4<R,T,A1,A2,A3,A4>,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   44  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf3<R,T,B1,B2,B3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3) const,A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   45  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf3<R,T,B1,B2,B3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3),A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   46  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf3<R,T,A1,A2,A3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3) const,A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   47  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf3<R,T,A1,A2,A3>,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3),A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   48  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf2<R,T,B1,B2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2) const,A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   49  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf2<R,T,B1,B2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2),A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   50  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf2<R,T,A1,A2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2) const,A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   51  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf2<R,T,A1,A2>,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2),A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   52  error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   53  error C2784: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf1<R,T,B1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1) const,A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   54  error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   55  error C2784: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf1<R,T,B1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1),A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   56  error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   57  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf1<R,T,A1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1) const,A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   58  error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   59  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf1<R,T,A1>,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(B1),A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   60  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(void) const,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   61  error C2780: 'boost::enable_if_c<!boost::core::is_same<T1,T2>::value,boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type>>::type boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(void),A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   62  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::cmf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(void) const,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   63  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,boost::_mfi::mf0<R,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(R (__thiscall T::* )(void),A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   64  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9),_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   65  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   66  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7),_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   67  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6),_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   68  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5),_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   69  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4),_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3,B4),A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   70  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3),_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2,B3),A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   71  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2),_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2),A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   72  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2),_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2),A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   73  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1,B2),_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1,B2),A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   74  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(B1),_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(B1),A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   75  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,R(__cdecl *)(void),boost::_bi::list0> boost::bind(R (__cdecl *)(void))' : expects 1 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   76  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   77  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   78  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   79  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   80  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   81  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   82  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2,A3)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   83  error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   84  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(F,A1,A2)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   85  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(F,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   86  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified,F,boost::_bi::list0> boost::bind(F)' : expects 1 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   87  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided    D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   88  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_8<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8)' : expects 10 arguments - 3 provided  D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   89  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_7<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)' : expects 9 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   90  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_6<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)' : expects 8 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   91  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_5<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)' : expects 7 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   92  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_4<A1,A2,A3,A4>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3,A4)' : expects 6 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   93  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_3<A1,A2,A3>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2,A3)' : expects 5 arguments - 3 provided D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   94  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_2<A1,A2>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1,A2)' : expects 4 arguments - 3 provided   D:\libs\zmq\zeromq_project\external_zmq\src\main.cpp    125 1   zmq_as_extrenal
Error   95  error C2784: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,F,A1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
```

Причина вероятно в перегруженном методе a::foo.
Либо я не правильно пытюсь забиндить функцию.

Как поправить данный код, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем коде есть несколько проблем:

1. Как вы правильно заметили, функция `foo` перегружена, поэтому необходимо явно указать нужную специализацию (`static_cast<void (b::*)(std::string&)>(&b::foo)`).
2. Если вы делаете bind на функцию-член класса, то обычно второй параметр должен быть *указателем* на объект класса (`&bb`). Если передать второй параметр по значению, будет создана его копия, и метод будет вызван для копии.
3. Если вы хотите, чтобы ссылка на переменную `s` попала в функцию `foo`, ее необходимо обернуть в `boost::ref` (`boost::ref(s)`). Если этого не сделать, то в `foo` будет передана ссылка на *копию* `s`, и все изменения проделанные c `a` в функции `foo` никак не отразятся на `s`.

В итоге получаем, что правильная запись `bind` в вашем случае должна выглядеть так:

```
 boost::bind(static_cast<void (b::*)(std::string&)>(&b::foo),
             &bb,
             boost::ref(s))
```

В моей версии boost (1.54) не получается передать результат в `boost::async`, т.к. `boost::async` похоже не имеет перегрузки для произвольных функторов (да и вообще почему-то нормальной документации по `boost::async` нагуглить не удается). С `boost::thread` работает:

```
auto func = boost::bind(static_cast<void (b::*)(std::string&)>(&b::foo),
                        &bb,
                        boost::ref(s));
boost::thread(func).join();
```

---

**PS**: в данном случае я бы посоветовал отказаться от `boost::bind` и использовать стандартные лямбды:

```
boost::thread([&bb, &s] { bb.foo(s); }).join();
```

Comment: Ну если уже использовать стандартные лямбды, то и `boost::thread` надо заменить на `std::thread`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду править.

Comment: в 59 бусте boost::async отработал

Answer (score 3):

Всё верно, из-за перегрузки компилятор не может вычислить тип нужной вам функции. Поэтому необходимо помочь ему, явно приведя указатель.

```cpp
boost::bind(static_cast<void (b::*) (std::string &)>(&b::foo), bb, s)
```

Всё это есть в официальной [документации](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.troubleshooting.binding_an_overloaded_function)